# Top Bar Confusion Foundation 6

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

What is the difference between class="title-bar" and class="top-bar-title" and class="title-bar-title" in Zurb Foundation 6? All of them appear to do the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

In Foundation 6, things have been "cut up" a lot more or made more "modular".

.title-bar is the container for .title-bar-title and any elements inside (usually a button toggle).

.title-bar-title is what is says - the title for the bar you are adding (often used in conjunction with a responsive menu).

.top-bar-title is similar to .title-bar-title but is specifically for the .top-bar element.

Although quite similar, they are all used for diving your markup semantically.

Read up on these:
http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/responsive-navigation.html
http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/top-bar.html

Answer (score 0):

.title-bar {background: #0a0a0a;color: #fefefe;padding: 0.5rem; }

.top-bar-title {float: left;margin-right: 1rem; }

.title-bar-title {font-weight: bold;vertical-align: middle;display: inline-block; }

I don't see there same thing